# Android studio can't run app after creating a new module

Tags: android, zoom-sdk

So I was trying integrate zoom into my app, in the process it requires me to add the zoom libraries to my own module, so I created one, but after creating the module, I can't run my app from the studio, it says module not specified.

When I was creating the module, there was an error in the following file

settings.gradle

```
include ':libsystem'
include ':mobilertc'
include ':commonlib' <component name ="libraryTable">
```

I deleted

```
<component name ="libraryTable">
```

error was gone.Do I need to include something in this file so that I can run my app?

Nvm, I deleted include':app' in settings.gradle by accident.

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps and see the example for zoom integration.

```
Step 1. Create an online zoom account for development.
```

[ZOOM Account Create](https://zoom.us/signin)

```
Step 2. Create a meeting using API or Manually.
Step 3. Initialize ZOOM SDK.
```

**Github:** [ZOOM SDK Integration](https://github.com/masum1161/ZoomSDKIntregration)

Answer (score 0):

i never using component name if using another module. as long I can use the file in that module, I think it's good.

Comment: I'm quite confused, I created a new project, and the app folder is one of the module, but for my current one, the app folder is not part of the module, is there any reason for that?